# animation not working

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuUWxUitJos
 and I made two poses and locked those pose and played the animation but I couldnot see the animation.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On your *Timeline*, you've enabled *Scaling* in the *Active Keying Set Used to Create/Delete Keyframe* field, so whatever you do with your bones, except scaling, it won't be recorded. So choose *LocRotScale*, or even disable this option and use <kbd>i</kbd> to insert keyframes manually.